# CSS How to extend the height of the menu/navigation to the footer?

Tags: jquery, css

I  created a slide out navigation which open and closes from normal nav size to slim nav size. and i want the navigation menu go all the way to the footer the beginging of the footer. Currently it overlaps the footer and doesnt go all the way to the footer.

How can I e extend the height of the navigation go all the way down and not overlap the footer but can push the footer down as needed.

Link to my working code [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/726o6w5q/11/)

JS

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

        /*
          $("ul.nav#main-menu li ").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("toggle-button-on").find(".fa-3x").removeClass("fa-3x").addClass("fa-lg");
          }); */
          $(".nav#main-menu ").on("click", ".toggle-button-on", function() {
            $(".toggle-button-on").toggleClass("toggle-button-on toggle-button-off");
            $(".nav .fa-lg").toggleClass("fa-lg fa-3x");
            $(".nav#main-menu .toggle-button").toggleClass("nav-slim");
            $(".nav#main-menu li a i").css(
            {
               'font-size' : '30px',
               'line-height' : '100px'
            });
            $(".nav#main-menu span").hide();
            $("#menu .navbar-side").css("width","64px");
            $("#menu").css("width","64px");
            $("#content-panel ").css("margin-left","100px");


            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('enable'); 
          });
          $(".nav#main-menu").on("click", ".toggle-button-off", function() {
            $(".toggle-button-off").toggleClass("toggle-button-off toggle-button-on");
            $(".nav .fa-3x").toggleClass("fa-3x fa-lg<></>");
            $(".nav#main-menu span").show();
            $(".nav#main-menu li a i").css(
            {
               'font-size' : '1em',
               'line-height' : ''
            });
            $("#menu .navbar-side").css("width","");
            $("#menu").css("width","");
             $("#content-panel ").css("margin-left","");
             $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('disable'); 
          });

       });
```

HTML

```
  <div class="subheader-bar">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="logo-b pull-left" style="border:none">
            <img src="./images/hello-moto-4.jpg" alt="Hello Moto" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
         <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <li><a href="bm_reportwriter_tpl-v3.html" class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-home  fa-2x "></i> <br>Home</a></li>  
            <li><a href="bm_summary_tpl.html" class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle  fa-2x "></i> <br>About</a></li>
              <li><a href="bm_linechart_tpl.html"  class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-area-chart fa-2x"></i> <br>Charts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"  class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></i> <br>Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x"></i> <br>FAQ's</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-list-ul fa-2x"></i><br> News</a></li>
          </ul> 
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
       <!-- Static Navigation --> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header  v-spacer1">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Moto Moto  </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right v-spacer1">
         <div class="input-group">
             <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button id="basic-search" class="btn btn-default " type="button" > <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
           </span>              
           <input type="text"  id="basicsearchVal" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a Ticker Symbol,CERT, BHCor a fragment of a Bank Name,." autocomplete="on">


              <span class="input-group-btn spacer-l">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"> Advanced Search</button>
             </span>   
            </div>

          </form> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>


<!-- End Navigation -->


    <!-- LEFT NAVIGATION -->
          <div id="control-panel">    
         <div id="menu">
            <nav class="navbar-default navbar-side" role="navigation">
             <div class="sidebar-collapse">

                    <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">
                      <li>
                          <a class="toggle-button-on"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Open/Close"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i><span> Open/Close</span></a>
                      </li>
                       <li>
                         <a ui-sref="Home"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="User1"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i><span> Welcome User1</span></a>
                       </li>

                       <li>
                         <a ui-sref="Home"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Home"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i><span> Home</span></a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                        <a ui-sref="ScenarioComparison"   data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Search"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i><span> Search</span></a>
                      </li>
                       <li ng-controller="scenarioController">
                        <a   data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Charts"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-lg"></i><span> Charts</span></a>
                      </li>
                       <li>
                        <a ui-sref="ScenarioComparison"   data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="WatchList"><i class="fa fa-table fa-lg"></i><span> Todays List</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a ui-sref="Dashboard"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="DashBoard"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i><span> FAQ</span></a>
                       </li>
                    </ul>

              </div>
            </nav>
         </div>        
    </div>

    <!-- END LEFT NAVIGATION -->

<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-11" style="width:500px; float:right">
   <h3 class="subheader" style="margin-top:50px"> Sample Info </h3>
        <div class="redmond">
        <p>
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
        </p>
            <table id="output"></table>

        </div>
     </div>
  </div>     
</div>     

<!-- begin footer -->   

    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="tbs-content-container" >
            <div class="tbs-content"  >
                <div class="tbs-row">
                    <div class="tbs-col tbs-w50 tbs-responsive" style="padding-top:12px;">
                        <p class="tbs-text-size-sm-1x" style="font-weight:bold;">HQ:</p>
                        <p class="tbs-text-size-sm-1x"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;3 moto ave,  Diagon Alley, NJ 07364</p>
                        <p class="tbs-text-size-sm-1x"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:info@totalbanksolutions.com">info@motowho.com</a></p>
                        <p class="tbs-text-size-sm-1x"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;(800) 300-MOTO</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tbs-col tbs-w50 tbs-responsive tbs-text-right">
                        <p><a href="index.html"><img class="tbs-responsive" src="images/moto_logo_transp.png" alt="moto Logo" style="max-width:150px"></a></p>
                        <p class="tbs-text-size-sm-2x" id="footer-copyright">© 2016 MOTO Who.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br><br>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: You could just change the height of your `margin-top`.

Comment: @Slacks- i want the height to go all the way to the beginning of the footer and not over lap the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to options here

**1st** using `position:fixed`

Use `position:fixed` to fix the menu to screen then it only needs `window` height, giving `height:100%` will do the job, here is the `css`

```
#control-panel{
   overflow:hidden;
   height:100%;
   width:auto;
   position:fixed;
   top:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   background-color:#34495e;
   margin-top:0px;
   z-index:9999; 
 }
```

See **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/726o6w5q/16/)**

**2nd** using position:absolute

If you want the menu to be `position:absolute`. Then you should need to find the `body` height by using jquery.

Then along with this `css`

```
#control-panel{
   overflow:hidden;
   height:100%;
   width:auto;
   position:absolute;
   top:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   background-color:#34495e;
   margin-top:0px;
   z-index:9999; 
 }
```

You have to use **jQuery**

**UPDATED**

```
var header_height = $(".navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top") .innerHeight() + $(".subheader-bar").innerHeight();

var height = $("body").innerHeight() - ($("footer").innerHeight() + header_height);
$("#control-panel").css({
          "height":(height - 10 )+"px",
          "top":(header_height + 10 )+"px"
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/726o6w5q/16/)**

Comment: @M Tanzil - Thank you .. But I dont want the navigation to overlap either the header or the footer. it should be between header and footer. Is that possible?

Comment: @M Tanzil - Thanks  i noticed that the navigation now is getting get cut off when it slim navigation. is there a way to make the footer go down or stay at the buttom so that the navigation extends to the top of the footer https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/726o6w5q/18/

Comment: I think that will be awkward if there is less content in you page and the #content-panel has height upto `845px` in your case it needs so it will look unsual, change `overflow:hidden` to `overflow-y:auto` in `#control-panel` that will be better for you. I think i will get +1 for this. Hope you got my point.